# How do I fetch an integer value and store it to a variable?

Tags: android

I am trying to input edittext value which is a number and save it to a variable which is of int type. i want to do some operation on that int int variable after that..
Here is the segment of that code.

```
inputNum = Integer.parseInt(Input.getText());
```

It gives me an error - The method parseInt(String) in the type integer is not applicable for the argument.

I need to store the numeric value entered in the edittext to the variable inputNum which is an integer type..
My Full Code

```
package com.shukla.rahul.mycalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView Display;
EditText Input;
Button X2, X3, Clear;
int result;
String Over = "Stopped";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //a = 1;
    //int inputNum = Integer.parseInt(Input.getText().toString());
    X2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bX2);
    X3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bX3);
    Clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClear);
    Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserinput);
    Display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    X2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int inputNum = Integer.parseInt(Input.getText().toString());
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (inputNum <= 10) {
                result = inputNum * 2;
                Display.setText("2 X " + inputNum + " = " + result);
                inputNum++;
            }else Display.setText("" + Over);
        }
    });
    X3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int inputNum = Integer.parseInt(Input.getText().toString());
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (inputNum <= 10) {
                result = inputNum * 3;
                Display.setText("3 X " + inputNum + " = " + result);
                inputNum++;
            }else Display.setText("" + Over);
        }
    });
    Clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            result = 0;
            //int inputNum = 1;
            Display.setText("" + result);
        }
    });
}
}
```

I am not sure as to where should I put this line of code

```
int inputNum = Integer.parseInt(Input.getText().toString());
```

and where should i declare the inputNum variable..eclipse shows no errors. but the app does'nt start..

Comment: Try `inputNum = Integer.parseInt(Input.getText().toString());`

Comment: Hey I edited my answer to adress your modified question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have some edit text:

```
EditText edit = (EditText) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.user_edit);
```

you would do the following:

```
String val = edit.getText().toString();
int value = Integer.valueOf(val);
```

EDIT:

You have:

```
X2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int inputNum = Integer.parseInt(Input.getText().toString());
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (inputNum <= 10) {
                result = inputNum * 2;
                Display.setText("2 X " + inputNum + " = " + result);
                inputNum++;
            }else Display.setText("" + Over);
        }
    });
```

you need to move:

```
int inputNum = Integer.parseInt(Input.getText().toString());
```

so that the method looks like:

```
X2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int inputNum = Integer.parseInt(Input.getText().toString());
                if (inputNum <= 10) {
                    result = inputNum * 2;
                    Display.setText("2 X " + inputNum + " = " + result);
                    inputNum++;
                }else Display.setText("" + Over);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where should this code that you suggested be placed in? as I applied this logic and the app crashes giving me a message that your app has stopped while lunching it self.

Comment: Edited to address.  Apply that change to any click listeners you have which need to use this value,.,.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting an error because `EditText.getText()` returns an `Editable`, not a `String`, and `Integer.parseInt(String s)` takes a `String` as a parameter.

Try:

```
// etInput is an EditText
int inputNum = Integer.valueOf(etInput.getText().toString());
```

In that case you are **converting the Editable to a String**, and therefore can be parsed.

Comment: This is probably the best since it explains that getText() returns editable.  We all address that issue, but this actually explicitly states it.

Comment: I applied the line of code that you suggested and it might work as well, as there are no errors found. but when i try to run the app.. its crashes and a message pops up saying ur app has stopped ..I think the declaration of the variable into which i want to store the edittext's value is not proper. I mean that placement of the variable..here is my full code.

Comment: Hi Philipp I have edited my code above. The app stops while launch.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Input` is of type `EditText`, then you have to do:

```
inputNum = Integer.parseInt(Input.getText().toString());
```